# I want to insert image path in database using MYSQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, mysqli

I want to insert image path in database.
In the browser when any user selects the image path and that image will store in image folder and path will store in database.
I tried but the if ($type==...) part is not working. It is going to the else statement.

Edited :

```
if (isset($_POST['bSubmit'])) {
 var_dump($_FILES);
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
     $type=var_dump($_FILES['file']['type']);



    if ($type == 'image/jpeg' || $type == 'image/png' || $type == 'image/gif') {
        if (file_exists(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/htdocs/Amit_404_Store/img/' . $name)) {
            echo 'file is already present';
        } else {
            $uploadimage = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/htdocs/Amit_404_Store/img/' . $name);
            echo "Stored in: " . "" . $name . "<br />";
            $destination = $name;
            echo "Upload in: " . "" . $destination . "<br />";

            //Database connection
            $servername = "Localhost";
            $username   = "root";
            $password   = "";
            $database   = "new_404_store2";

            //session value store and retrive data for index.html file
            $email = $_SESSION['user_name1'];

            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

            $Update_query = "update customer_information2 set Image_Path='$destination' where Email_Id='$email'";

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $Update_query);



            if (!$result) {
                die('Could not enter data: ' . mysqli_error());
            }


            if ($uploadimage) {
                echo 'image uploaded and stored';
            } elseif (!$uploadimage) {
                echo 'image not uploaded';
            }

        }
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type';
    }
}

//mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: What error you are getting

Comment: i am getting else part message   'Invalid file type'

Comment: cursor not checking this code                   if ($type == 'image/jpeg' || $type == 'image/png' || $type == 'image/gif') {

Comment: are you certain whether the $type is one of above?

Comment: where should i type this code.

Comment: sorry shan i am not understand..please explain

Comment: After if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { var_dump($_FILES)

Comment: @Narendraverma : type it inside first if

Comment: @Narendraverma I asked you sure the file you uploaded is one of jpg gif or png ?

Comment: $type =var_dump($_FILES['file']['type']);      i am getting error NULL Invalid file type

Comment: only var_dump($_FILES['file']['type']);

Comment: @Narendraverma oops. don't type it in front of $type. just add it as a new line.

Comment: @Narendraverma var_dump($_FILES)  will give you whats inside $_FILES variable.

Comment: output:-NULL Invalid file type

Comment: Show  your form  code

Comment: <form method="post" action="example4.php" id="frmOrderDetailsGraphic" class="" autocomplete="off">
     <div id="fileUpload">
      <input type="file" id="file"  name="file" required >
      <input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" value="">
     </div>
     <div id="upload-msg">
      <p>Upload your favourite Graphic above</p>
      <!--<button class="fs-submit" type="button">Place Order</button>-->
      <input type="submit" name="bSubmit" size="10" >
     </div>
    </form>

Comment: Hello Shan, I tried this also but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You have not written enctype,it is required for file transfer

```
<form method="post" action="example4.php" id="frmOrderDetailsGraphic" class="" autocomplete="off"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Hello Abhi, i tried this also but again i am getting output Invalid file type

Comment: your submit button name is bSubmit  so your first line should be if (isset($_POST['bSubmit'])) {

Comment: yes, that code is correct i written if (isset($_POST['bSubmit'])) only

Comment: Check your code you have posted you have written if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

Comment: if (isset($_POST['bSubmit'])) {

    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $type=var_dump($_FILES['file']['type']);

Comment: Sorry Abhi, I tried this code also but else part is running only output is invalid file type

Comment: post your updated form in question, so that it can be readable

Comment: Hey abhi i tried below code and it working perfectly                                                 <?php
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
$size=$_FILES["file"]["size"];
$error=$_FILES["file"]["error"];

if ((($type == "image/gif") || ($type == "image/jpeg") || ($type == "image/png")) && ($size < 100000)) {

  if ($error > 0) {
    echo "File Error :  " . $error . "<br />";
  }
  else {
    if (file_exists(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) ."/htdocs/Amit_404_Store/img/" . $name)) {
      echo "<b>" . $name . " already exists. </b>";
    }

Comment: else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/htdocs/Amit_404_Store/img/' . $name);
      echo "Stored in: " . "" .$name . "<br />";
      $destination = "" .$name;
      

//Database connection
            $servername = "Localhost";
            $username   = "root";
            $password   = "";
            $database   = "new_404_store2";

            //session value store and retrive data for index.html file
            $email = $_SESSION['user_name1'];

            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

Comment: if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

            $Update_query = "update customer_information2 set Image_Path='$destination' where Email_Id='$email'";

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $Update_query);



            if (!$result) {
                die('Could not enter data: ' . mysqli_error());
            }
    }
  }
}
else {
  echo "Invalid file detail ::<br /> file type ::" . $type . " , file size::: " . $size;
}

?>

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($type == 'image/jpeg' || $type == 'image/png' || $type == 'image/gif') {
```

should be

```
if ($type == 'image/jpeg' || $type == 'image/jpg' || $type == 'image/png' || $type == 'image/gif') {
```

if u are adding image file and still getting error